# How to set mulitple records in constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm not using this in a real app but I was just curious on how to do this (C#).

I set one record of sample data in the constructor :

```
public class MikesClass
{
    public MikesClass()
    {
     Id = 01; Name = "Mike";      
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

but I'm confused on how to set another record in it :

```
public MikesClass()
        {
         Id = 01; Name = "Mike";  

         Id = 02;  Name = "Tom"; ???

        }
```

If possible to do this, what is the syntax? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You completely misunderstood what a constructor is. A constructor is for `one single object`. It creates one single object. Thus you cannot set another record with it. That record will be a different object. You just set the values as arguments to constructor when you create another record.

So, should at least be like this -

```
public class MikesClass
{
    public MikesClass(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id; 
        Name = name;      
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and in some distance place when creating multiple records/objects -

```
var m1 = new MikesClass(0,"name1");
var m2 = new MikesClass(1, "name2");
```

Comment: A constructor creates an _instance_.

Comment: Excellent explanation, thanks. I struggle with OOP but keep practicing it to hopefully understand it better one day.

Answer (score 2):

Using the code you specified above, each time you write:

```
MikesClass mc = new MikesClass();
```

you will get an object of type `MikesClass` with the `Id` property set to 1 and the `Name` property set to "Mike".  Since each instance of MikesClass represents a single object, you cannot have multiple objects represented within it.

What you can do though, is modify your constructor to take the two values as parameters.  Like this:

```
public MikesClass(int id, string name)
{
    Id = id;
    Name = name;
}
```

You can then use this code to create multiple `MikesClass` objects like so:

```
MikesClass mike = new MikesClass(1, "Mike");
MikesClass tom = new MikesClass(2, "Tom");
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: thanks, but that didn't' answer the question. I know how to do that other stuff, but just wanted to know how to do what I asked.

Comment: I guess that's a fair point.  You can't do what you're specifically looking to do.  You could however, use a list structure of some sort inside of your class and pass multiple values in via the constructor.  That would kind of get you there.

Comment: The answer below summed it up "You completely misunderstood what a constructor is." I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 2):

What you're showing is a constructor. It is run when you create an instance of the MikeClass class.
What you want is to create several instances. Maybe in an array?

```
MikeClass[] array = new MikeClass[2];
    MikeClass mc = new MikeClass(); /first instance
    mc.Id = 1;
    mc.Name = "Mike";
    array[0] = mc;
    mc = new MikeClass(); //another instance
    mc.Id = 2;
    mc.Name = "Tom";
    array[1] = mc;
};
```

This is using object initializer syntax:

```
MikeClass[] array = new MikeClass[] {
    new MikeClass { Id = 1, Name = "Mike" }, //first instance
    new MikeClass { Id = 2, Name = "Tom" }  //another instance
};
```

You can also create a constructor for the MikeClass class that takes parameters:

```
public MikeClass(int id, string name) {
    Id = id;
    Name = name;
}
```

Then:

```
MikeClass[] array = new MikeClass[] {
    new MikeClass(1, "Mike"),
    new MikeClass(2, "Tom")
};
```