# Why is the constructor invoked many times?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, constructor, silverlight-5.0

I am working on silverlight. I created a TextBox and when ever user changed any text  in that it should  show "*" at the top of file and which should disappear on clicking a save button.

My code works fine for one textbox but when i create second textbox (after the first one) then i found that constructor is invoked two times instead of one. And when i create third textbox(after the two) the constructor is invoked 3 times instead of one. (this textbox is created on a button click in my GUI dynamically which has some text written on it and when i make some change in that text then it shows "*" at top and which disappears on saving it).

Whereas i expect it to be invoked 1 time if i add 1 textbox at a time.
My code to do so is:

```
private bool modified;
public bool Modified
 {
    get { return modified; }
    set { modified = value; OnPropertyChanged("Modified"); }
 }

public ClassConstructor(AnotherClass pv) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Number of call check");
    setStar(false);
    this.isModified = false;
}

private void setStar(bool modified) 
{

    Tab = this.FileName;
    if (modified == false)
    {
        Tab += "";
    } 
  else 
  {
        Tab += " *";
    }
    Modified = modified;
}
public void TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox) sender;
    setStar(!TextData.Equals(tb.Text));
}
public void SaveCode(object para) 
{
    TextData.txt = txt;
    setStar(false);
}
```

**Why this constructor is called so many times ?** (I mean why my MessageBox for times if i create the fourth textbox) ?

Comment: `DelegateCommand` class constructor what does it do ? I suspect you are not removing methods from delegates

Comment: It seems that the problem is in the other part of the code.

Comment: @Arjuna delegatecommand saves the change done in textbox by user dynamically whereas cancel cancels the textbox.

Comment: @user234839 please show more code, where you are using `saveCodeCmd` and `cancelCodeCmd`

Comment: @Arjuna even if i show these two things it do not change anything. Because they are working fine. The problem is why the constructor is instantiated the number of times the number textbox i create. (if the textbox created is5th number it is invoked 5 times).

Comment: Show the code where you create the textboxes - I'd guess that you are subscribing to the click event multiple times

Comment: Do you know what a constructor is? May be this answer will help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596096/how-to-set-mulitple-records-in-constructor/24596162#24596162

Comment: @user234839 Don't be so quick to dismiss offers of help by saying that 'it do not change anything'. YOU don't know what the problem is, otherwise you'd fix it. Others are trying to help and you should act on their suggestions if you want help. Maybe they know something you don't (which is why you are asking for help right?)

Comment: @Mashton this constructutor is instantiated in foreach loop this is the problem . I just got it.  but do not know how to make solution.

Comment: Is it possible in chat room ?

Answer (score 2):

A constructor creates one single instance of that class. So whenever you create a new instance (in your case a new `TextBox`) the constructor is called to create that object instance. This the sole purpose of constructor - `To Be Called when you create an object of that class`. Therefore the code inside that constructor is executed. Since you are showing `MessageBox` inside constructor, you are seeing it 5 times, for 5 new objects and 4 times for 4 new objects. As said in the wiki -

> Instance constructors, sometimes referred to as .ctor, are used to
>   create and initialize any instance member variables when the new
>   expression is used to create an object of a class.

My first suggestion - Learn what a constructor is because unless you know what a constructor is, you will never understand why this happening. BTW, this is not the error, this is the feature of Object Oriented Programming that whenever you create a new instance, the constructor will be called.

A very good starting point will be here -

[Constructor (object-oriented programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming))